# What is the complexity to break second preimage resistance?

Tags: hash, 2nd-preimage-resistance

In the context an of hash functions we have three required properties.

1. Preimage resistance
2. Second preimage resistance
3. Collision resistance.

The bounds for Pre image collision is $O(2^{n-1})$, the bounds for collision resistance is $2^{n/2}$, what are the bounds for breaking second preimage resistance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The right terminology is **second preimage resistance** and **preimage resistance**.

**Edited** to reflect comment by otus. Preimage attack takes $O(2^{n})$ hash function calls on average.

Second preimage attack takes just one extra call so the complexity is essentially the same as that of the preimage attack. Given $x$ you want $x'\neq x$ such that $H(x)=H(x').$ So evaluate $H(x)$ for one extra query, and then apply the preimage attack to $y=H(x).$